# What is the meaning of word "of" or "more of "?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

You know, Ron says he thinks I see more of my secretary, Ethel, (she indicates off) than him. What is the meaning of word "of" or "more of "? from book "Harry Potter and the Cursed Child"

Answer (score 2):

If you 'see a lot of' someone, you meet them frequently or spend a lot of time in their company (either by choice or because you happen to work together). The speaker spends more time with Ethel than she does with Ron.

Answer (score 2):

"of" is a very common and very versatile word in English.

In this context—"see more **of** [a person] than [another person]"—I think the meaning is best given by [Sense 6 at wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/of#Preposition), specifically 6.3:

> 6. *Introducing subject matter.*
>
> 1. *Links an intransitive verb, or a transitive verb and its subject (especially verbs to do with thinking, feeling, expressing etc.), with its subject-matter;* concerning, with regard to.
>    *I'm always thinking **of** you.*
> 2. *(following a noun (now chiefly nouns of knowledge, communication etc.)) Introduces its subject matter;* about, concerning.
>    *He told us the story **of** his journey to India.*
> 3. *(following an adjective) Introduces its subject matter.*
>    *This behaviour is typical **of** teenagers.*